# How to use ajax to add row to database with a many to many relationship?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm trying to add a row to a database using Ajax. The database is named Order and has a many to many relationship with a database named Dish. The Order database is made of a list of dishes and a orderPrice of type Int.

I have a button called print that I would like that when clicked would create a new row in the order database, so Ill be able to create a view to show all orders that have been made in the past.
these are my models:

Dish Model:

```
  public partial class Dish
    {
       
        public Dish()
        {
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }
    
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        public string DishPrice { get; set; }
    
       
       
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Order model:

```
public partial class Order
    {
        
        public Order()
        {
            this.Dishes = new HashSet<Dish>();
        }
    
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Orderprice { get; set; }
    
 
        public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the controller for the view where the print button is:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private MenuDBEntities db = new MenuDBEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categories.ToList());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Order order)
        {
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            
            return View();
        }
      
    }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function print() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Index",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            Dishes: JSON.stringify(order),
            OrderPrice: JSON.stringify(sum)
        },
        dataType: "json",
        
    });

}
```

order is an array with an element of type dish in each index, and sum is a variable of type int.
This is my first time using Ajax and I have a strong feeling that I missed something big.

Any advice would be highly appreciated! and if any more information is needed please ask

TIA

Comment: The first thing I'd do is change `data` to `JSON.stringify({ Dishes: order, OrderPrice: sum})` because what you have is a mishmash and might possibly send `[object Object]` as the body of the request, or something even worse.

Comment: hey Chris G I tried that but still no results. do you have any other advice?